# Is there any way to automate refreshing the credentials in Azure Analysis Service

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-analysis-services

Is there any way to automate refreshing the credentials in Azure Analysis Service. I need to use a SQL user or a Azure SPN to connect to SQL from Azure Analysis service. I am able to use SQL user to connect by refreshing the credential manually. Could we automate this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no automatic way to do that, you need to refresh the credential manually.